# Como hacer la union de tablas en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Trate de unir las tablas pero no puede aqui el codigo de la sentencia

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario AS u, materiales AS m WHERE ";
  $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta) OR DIE("Error al Ejecutar Consulta de Usuario y Materiales".mysqli_error($conexion)  );
```

*Imagen de la Tabla de Usuario*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Imagen de la Tabla de Materiales*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Le hacen falta parámetros a tu where

Comment: Podría ser algo así `SELECT * FROM usuario AS u  INNER JOIN materiales m on   u.materiales=m.idMateriales` aunque puede variar dependiendo de que resultado intente obtener , como consejo revisar https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Me gustaria ponerle una condicional WHERE, donde se utilizaria la id del usuario para seleccionar o unir la otra tabla materiales con la misma posicion del id del usuario

Comment: La solución es como te dice @Dev.Joel, agregando el WHERE al final : `SELECT * FROM usuario u INNER JOIN materiales m on u.materiales=m.idMateriales WHERE u.id=el id usuario que quieres`

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quieres un producto natural entre la tabla `usuario` y la tabla `materiales`, por lo que vi en tus tabla usuarios tiene una columna llamada materiales sobre esa columna debes hacer el `inner join`, de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario INNER JOIN materiales ON usuario.materiales=materiales.idMateriales
```

si quieres agregar una condición, solo hace falta poner el `where` al final de la sentencia de arriba y recuerda que debes especificar sobre que tabla quiere hacer el `where` por ejemplo:

```
... where usuarios.id=[lo que busques]
```